# I want to stop the Discord Bot from running

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I'm doing something with a discord bot, and I got stuck in this.

let's say this is `callBot_and_sendmessage` function

```py
       def callBot_and_sendmessage(message):
                #wake the bot
                @client.event
                async def on_ready():    
                        await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name='Do !help'))
             
                #send the message
                @client.event
                async def on_message(message):
                        channel = client.get_channel(channelId)
                        await channel.send(message)
```

and my code is like this

```py
message = input('Type a message: ')
callBot_and_sendmessage(message)
saveMessage(message)
```

the function `saveMessage`

```py
def saveMessage(message):
    with open(file, 'w') as fileData:
        fileData.write(message)
```

My program won't call the  `saveMessage` Function
so I need a way to stop the `callBot_and_sendmessage` aka the bot from running after sending the message

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the bot log out by using [client.close()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=logout#discord.Client.close). Alternatively you can put `exit(0)` at the end (after the `channel.send`), so the script stops running after the message has been sent.